# LaTeX interaction with the OCaml toplevel system

Tags: highlighting, python

I would like to be able to write an [OCaml](http://ocaml.org) expression inside a LaTeX document, and have it loaded in the OCaml toplevel system, which would compile it and evaluate it. Then both the expression and its result would be typeset with syntax highlighting.

It could be some environment like

```
\begin{ocamltoplevel}
  let x = 2 + 3*4}
\end{ocamltoplevel}
```

How can I accomplish this?

That is the same idea provided by the `pyconsole` environment from the [PythonTeX](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex) package. PythonTeX supports addition of more languages. Maybe someone could add OCaml to the list.

Comment: For future reference:  [PythonTeX issue discussing the possibility of adding OCaml support](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/62)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I don't have OCaml these days but I have Fsharp which isn't totally different...

I'm using `minted` which uses pymentize to do the syntax highlighting, pygments has an fsharp lexer, but not a specific lexer for fsharp *output* although parsing it as input as done here makes a reasonable attempt at sensible colouring.

the input is directly handed to `minted`, the output is written to a temporary file
and then input to `minted`. `minted` (and the extra file writing done here) requires `pdflatex --shell-escape`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{fsharp}
let x = 2 + 3*4
\end{minted}

\immediate\write18{echo "let x = 2 + 3*4" | fsi> \jobname.tmp}
\inputminted{fsharp}{\jobname.tmp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As of `pygmentize == 2.2.0`, OCaml syntax is available: http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-ml-family-languages (also `pygmentize -L lexers | ag ocaml`). For example, `\inputminted[linenos,breaklines]{ocaml}{foo.ml}`.